# How to run a vim script interactively from vim command line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

**Is there a way to run these scripts from the `:` commandline with a few keystrokes?**

Over the last couple of months, I've built a series of files full of vim-commands to auto-generate boilerplate code for my projects.  It's allowed me to work faster.

However, the only way I know how to run these scripts is by assigning them to key-combinations in `~/.vimrc`.  There's only so many keys I can remap.

Is there a way to run these scripts from the `:` commandline with a few keystrokes?

For example, I have a `unit_test_cpp.vim` script, which builds a boilerplate unit test cpp file.  I'd like to be able to type

```
:utc
```

or some other simple combination of letters with a simple mnemonic to run this script on my currently open file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `command` feature of vim. In your `unit_test_cpp.vim` file you would add something like this:

```
command Utc call CreateUnitTests()
```

Now when you type `:Utc` it will call your function. The only limitation is that your command must start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 30):

Open Vim and enter the following:

```
:source /path/to/vim/file/name.vim
```

If you are currently editing that file, you can also type:

```
:w <ENTER>
:source % <ENTER>
```

The percent sign (%) means the path to the currently opened file.

Answer (score 5):

Script or function? If it is a function, try

```
:call FunctionName()
```

Comment: They are files with vim commands.  I can run them with the so command.

Comment: Each of the so commands is wrapped by a function in .vimrc.  So could I use the :call FunctionName() method to run those functions from .vimrc?

Comment: basically.  if you had  
    function! Foo()
       source 'foo.vim'
    endfunction
you could could  :call Foo() and it should source foo.vim, or you can map the command as rq suggests below to avoid the :call...

Answer (score 1):

```
:run file.vim
```

`:run` is like `:source`, but `:run` doesn't need the path.  It searches the `runtimepath`.

A Linux `runtimepath`:

```
$HOME/.vim,
$VIM/vimfiles,
$VIMRUNTIME,
$VIM/vimfiles/after,
$HOME/.vim/after
```